# Array of 20 rolls of one die in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm working on an exercise that requires that I print 20 rolls of a die out and group repeated values in parentheses. My code below follows the pseudocode the book I'm reading says to use. I am able to group the repeated values in parentheses but the next exercise requires that I group the values that are repeated the most in parentheses.

For example:

(333)51314121(22)326(55)14

would be:

(333)51314121223265514

EDIT: If there is more than one largest group of repeated values only the first is to be grouped in parentheses.

How can I accomplish this? Many thanks in advance for any help on this.

```
public void run() {

    Random generator = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {
        int die = generator.nextInt(6)+ 1;
        a.add(die);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < a.size() - 1; j++) {
        if (inRun) {
             if (a.get(j) != a.get(j - 1)) {
                 System.out.print(")");
                 inRun = false;
             }

        }
        else {
            if (a.get(j) == a.get(j + 1)) {
                System.out.print("(");
                inRun = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(a.get(j));

    }
    if (inRun) {
        System.out.print(")");
    }

}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? What does your code do that's wrong?  Have you tried debugging it step by step in an IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans)?

Comment: You have to change your algorithm. Basically, you must iterate the values and remember the position of the highest number of repeated values. Then you update the view (insert brackets).

Comment: Rather than tackle that exercise, I'd give you a more useful one.  Rewrite the code so it doesn't depend on looking one element beyond the current one, and thus does not need the input array to be one larger than you need.  In "real life" you won't be allowed to do things like that.

Comment: The code above works fine but doesn't depict an attempt to solve the problem. I have thought of looping through the array before printing and storing the location of the beginning of the largest set and the end of the largest set and printing "(" and ")" respectively but I wasn't sure if that was appropriate so I stopped and came here for some advice.

Comment: I will work out something going by what you said. Thanks Jim.

Comment: After you've done that, then pay attention to @home's suggestion.  Having solved my exercise you'll be in a better position to solve your original problem.

Comment: What if there is more than one largest sequence? Will it have to group both or just the first?

Comment: @JimGarrison a lookahead of 1 simply won't work, real life or not

Comment: If there is more than one largest sequence only the first is to be grouped. I should have specified that.

Comment: Just curious... what book gave you that code?  I'd be wary of the book's quality if that algorithm was given as the correct solution.

Comment: It is Java Concepts 6th edition by Cay Horstman. I took a java class a couple years ago but they only covered up to arrays. I'm currently trying to finish it. That was pseudocode recommended by the exercise itself rather than a solution though. I'm trusting you guys vs this pseudo.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a data structure other than an ordinary array.

You can make it ***O(n)*** by checking while inserting:

- If the **added number** equals the **previous**, you increment the *sequence count* - if not, you reset the count.
- When you increment a *sequence count*, check if it is bigger than the already stored *max sequence count* length - if it is bigger, the current *sequence count* **becomes** the *max sequence count*.

Check the code - some comments there to help understanding ([**run demo online here**](http://ideone.com/JADjbT)):

```
public void run() {
    Random generator = new Random();
    int[] a = new int[20];

    int biggerSequence = 1;         // starts pointing to the first char
    int biggerSequenceEndIndex = 1; // starts pointing to the first char
    int currentSequence = 1;
    int previous = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        int die = generator.nextInt(6)+ 1;
        a[i] = die;
        if (die == previous) { // if inserted equals previous
            currentSequence++; // increment sequence
            if (currentSequence > biggerSequence) { // if it is bigger than max
                biggerSequence = currentSequence; // max becomes it
                biggerSequenceEndIndex = i+1;
            }
        } else {
            previous = die;
            currentSequence = 1; // reset the count
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
       if (i == biggerSequenceEndIndex-biggerSequence) { System.out.print("("); }
       System.out.print(a[i]);
       if (i+1 == biggerSequenceEndIndex) { System.out.print(")"); }
    }
}
```

Example outputs:

```
(1)2345678901234567890
(11)345678901234567890
1(22)45678901234567890
1(22)45578901234567890
123456789012345678(99)
54(3333)43514564513551
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try storing the number of repeated values starting at any given index. Something like:

```
public void run(){

    Random generator = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++) {//Generate your numbers
        int die = generator.nextInt(6)+ 1;
        a.add(die);
    }

    //store the number of repeats by index. (index is key, # of repeats is key)
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> repeats = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    //This will find store the number of repeated numbers starting at any given index.
    int index = 0;
    repeats.put(index, 1);
    for(int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++){
        if(a.get(i) == a.get(index)){//Repeated values occurring
            repeats.put(index, repeats.get(index) + 1);
        } else {//End of a repeated sequence (even if that sequence was only 1 number long)
            repeats.put(i, 1);
            index = i;
        }
    }

    //Find the index at which the maximum number of repeats occurs
    int max = 0;
    int startIndex = 0;
    for(Integer i : repeats.keySet()){
        //If the number of repeats is bigger than anything seen before
        if(repeats.get(i) > max){
            //Store the number of repeats and the index at which they start
            max = repeats.get(i);
            startIndex = i;
        }
    }

    //print everything out
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        if(i == startIndex)//Prints the open parenthesis before the repeats start
            System.out.print("(");
        System.out.print(a.get(i)); //Prints the number
        if(i == startIndex + max)
            System.out.print(")");//Prints the close parenthesis after the repeats end
    }
}
```

Note that this algorithm assumes that there is only 1 repeated sequence of the maximum size. Should there be multiple that you want to keep, you'll have to store all indexes in another list. But that's a minor fix to the solution that would look like so:

```
ArrayList<Integer> startIndeces = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int max = 0;
for(Integer i : repeats.keySet()){
    //If the number of repeats is bigger than anything seen before
    if(repeats.get(i) > max){
        //Store the number of repeats and the index at which they start
        max = repeats.get(i);
        startIndeces = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        startIndeces.add(i);
    } else if(repeats.get(i) == max)
        startIndeces.add(i);
}
```

Otherwise the algorithm stores the first instance of the longest sequence.

Comment: There are a few concepts here that I have not been exposed to such as HashMap. Jim commented on my initial post above and recommended that I rewrite the loop so that is doesn't look one ahead of the current one. I didn't get as far as writing any code but storing an integer and incrementing it or setting index to i is the idea I was pondering on. Is this what he was referring to? I definitely want to learn to code that is usable in "real life". He may be able to jump in and confirm I'm still learning how this site works so I'm not sure if he will get a notification for a comment on an answer.

Comment: That's interesting and worth a try. The HashMap is just another way to store information and you'll eventually get around to it. I'm not quite sure what his "real life" scenario is referring to because sometimes you can use as much memory as you want if it speeds up the solution, sometimes you can't. It depends on your boss and the problem at hand. Good luck solving though!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make multiple passes over the array. Go through it once and tally up how long all the runs are. Then decide what the maximum run length is. Finally, go back and print out the array, putting parentheses around runs of the maximum length.

Try something like this (exact implementation left to you):

```
runContents = a list containing the first random number
runLength = [1], i.e. a one element list with the number 1 in it
maxLength = 1
for each subsequent random number you want to consider {
  if the last element of runContents == the next random number {
    add 1 to the last element of runLength
  } else {
    if maxLength < the last element of runLength {
      maxLength = the last element of runLength
    }
    append the random number to runContents
    append a 1 to runLength
  }
}

i = 0
while i < length(runContents) {
  if runLength[i] == maxLength {
    print runLength[i] copies of runContents[i] surrounded by parens
  } else {
    print runLength[i] copies of runContents[i]
  }
}
```